# Unable to access a server cotrol on page_load method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have place holder in my aspx page inside html table as below:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" onmouseover="divexpand()" onmouseout="collapsediv()">
    <span id="sp"><i>Status:</i></span>
        <div id="div2" style="display:block;">
        <table style="padding:10px;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>A:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and i'm trying to access the placeholders 'ph1' and 'ph2' on page_load method code behind using Page.FindControl(id) method as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph1 = Page.FindControl("ph1") as PlaceHolder;
        PlaceHolder ph2 = Page.FindControl("ph2") as PlaceHolder;
        ph1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b><i>TEST</i></b>"));
        ph2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b><i>TEST</i></b>"));
    }
```

But I could not access the placeholders. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using FindControl? Are they not accessible using purely their ID?

Comment: Why can't you access directly by `id`?

Comment: @cstruter Finding controls is necessary if the same control is inside any listing control like `GridView`, `ListView`...

Comment: @ChrisBint: as you suggested the control could be accessed directly with their ID. Thanks

Comment: @user3240361 Added an appropriate answer in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use FindControl in this context. Simple access the PlaceHolder controls directly from code-behind using their respective IDs.

Answer (score 1):

you should add controls to [placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/wwbbhe6w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from code behind without Page.FindControl